# How can I check if a notification is running?

Tags: android

I've seen the other answers but I'd like not to involve a broadcast receiver. Keep in mind **I don't want to know when a notification is dismissed**. What I want is, when issuing a new notification, to previously check if the notification of id 'x' is still there.

```
int ID_NOTIFICATION = 0 //check if notification with this id is running
mainNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setContentTitle("something")
                .setContentText(notificationText)
                .setTicker("Notification!")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .build();

C.notificationManager.notify(ID_NOTIFICATION, mainNotification);
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: it will update the old notification if its there, if its not it will be created, why check then.

Comment: @Elltz Obviously I had thought of that, elltz, hence the reason why I'm asking this here. The rest is plainly irrelevant. So, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at the documentation of [NotificationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) tells us that checking the existence of a notification is not part of the notification API.

If you really need to know whether or not a notification exists you need to keep track of it yourself. I assume you were already told how that works.

On Android 4.3 or newer you could implement a [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html). But that's even more work and requires user interaction to enable the notification listener.